# Не отображается нужная картинка при шаринге в facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, opengraph

Здравствуйте, на сайте http://fabricon.com.ua (WP) есть разметка Open Graph, сделанная с помощью плагина Yoast Seo. Но при публикации в Facebook картинки вытягиваются рандомно, хотя og:img указано. На официальном сайте Open Graph я проверил разметку, все данные верны - http://opengraphcheck.com/result.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffabricon.com.ua#.Wngc265l_IU
Здесь же https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ я вижу, что подтянуло все картинки на сайте, кроме нужной, нажимал "Получить новую информацию" ничего не менялось. Может кто-то сталкивался с таким?

Comment: Попробуйте ещё добавить размеры изображения:
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630">

Comment: А по поводу "Получить новую информацию" там у них на какой-то вкладке ещё есть "сбросить кэш". Прежде, чем получать информацию, нужно его сбросить тоже.